# GitHub API - for changing file permissions

Tags: github, github-api

Is there a clear way to change file permissions with GitHub APIs (v3). This is a rare use case, but we have a reason. We couldn't find a one, any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [V3 API has ways to update a file](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file), there doesn't appear to be a way to change its permissions in a simple way.

File permissions are stored in the tree object (basically a directory), and [V3 allows you direct access to the underlying objects](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/). You can, conceivably, [get the tree object holding the correct blob (file)](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree) and [replace it with a new tree object with your changed permissions](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree).

Github has also introduced its new [V4 GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) which has more extensive access to the repository, but requires understanding GraphQL. Again you can find the correct [Tree](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/tree/) and [TreeEntry](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/treeentry/) and create a new Tree and TreeEntry with the new mode.

While GraphQL is very powerful and worth learning if you're going to do a lot of work with the Github API, it might be simpler to just clone the repo and do it with Git.